# what does !function() means in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can read and write some `JavaScript`, but today I came across a `.js` file starting with

```
!function() {
 /*
  code here
 */
}.call(window);
```

**Question**

what does `!` infront of `function` means?

Comment: that's "not" a function i've seen before...

Comment: @sircapsalot Please stop. You're killing me.

Comment: That's just a normal use of the `!` operator, which returs the opposite of a boolean value.  If the anonymous function returns `true`, the `!` negates the result so that it's `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns "not" (!) of the result of a calling the anonymous function with a "this" of window.

Answer (score 1):

Negating the result of `.call(window)`.  Not the function.

Comment: But `.call(window)` is in fact calling the `function`, is it not (no pun intended)?